How can I sort a filter function using custom column arrangement and not have headers included in the sorting?
I was able to get this formula to work for the filter where I have columns AE and AF selected.
When I tried doing adding a sort portion to the formula it mixed the headers in with it, the formula mixed the headers in with the listed data.
Original:
=FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},AF:AF,AE:AE),AE:AE>0)

Sorting in ascending order for 1st column:
=SORT(FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},AF:AF,AE:AE),AE:AE>0),1,1)

Is there a way to not have the headers included in the sorting?
Note: The data set is not a table and I cannot make it into a table per Client doesn't want the raw data transformed.
Resource for custom columns:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCQAweoAdOw

update: 10/4/24
I tried using teh DROP part as suggested but i got the NAME? error, so the version i have doesn't allow me to use DROP. - Thank you Though.

Try using DROP(yourFilteredRange, 1) before sorting.

Is the titles in AF1 and AE1? You can try “AF2:AF1048576” and "AF2:AF1048576" to represent the data ranges.

FYI, a table does not transform raw data.

Since per OP's post as they don't have access to the DROP() function, then could use the following formula as well in order to accomplish the desired output:


=LET(
     _Vals, A:A,
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(_Vals<>"")),
     _Nvals, A2:INDEX(_Vals,_LastRow),
     _Name, F2:INDEX(F:F,_LastRow),
     SORT(FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},_Name,_Nvals),_Nvals>0)))


So, with respect to the ranges per OP:
=LET(
     _A, AE:AE,
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(_A<>"")),
     _NA, AE2:INDEX(_A,_LastRow),
     _B, AF2:INDEX(AF:AF,_LastRow),
     SORT(FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},_B,_A),_A>0)))


Note that the above formula is basing on column AE whose last non empty cell has been taken as the base last row for all the other columns included.

Or, Could use something like this as well:
=LET(
     a, FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},AF:AF,AE:AE),AE:AE>0),
     SORT(INDEX(a, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)-1,,2),{1,2})))





Worked perfectly!!!!! thank you so much!! i just put my own headers!!!

Glad to know that. Thanks!

Try:
SORT(DROP(FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},AF:AF,AE:AE),AE:AE>0),1),1,1)

